# Python tkinter restarting the mainwindow while its running

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have a complex program where I run multiple tasks in my tkinter mainloop. My program is working however I am having one annoying problem, I do not have an ability to stop a task unless its finished. I have developed a simple tkinter program to show this problem:

Full code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button,Entry,Canvas,Label,ttk


class Application(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
    def Create_canvas(self,canvas_width,canvas_height):
        global canvas#described as global because used outside class
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master,bg='papaya whip',width=canvas_width,height=canvas_height)
       
    def Application_Intro(self):
        print("starting new app")
        restart_program_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Restart_program",font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, height=2, command =self.Restart)
        start_program_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Start_program",font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, height=2, command =self.Start_program)     
        canvas.create_text(960,20,text="MY PROGRAM",font='Helvetica 16 bold')
        canvas.create_window(710,300,window = restart_program_button)
        canvas.create_window(710,500,window = start_program_button)
        canvas.pack()
        self.master.mainloop()
        
        
        
    def Start_program(self):
        print("Program start")
        self.master.after(1000,self.Start_program)
        
    def Restart(self):
        #self.master.destroy()
        #self.master.quit()
        print("HERE I WANT TO INTERRUPT START PROGRAM AND RETURN TO IDLE STATE")

        #WHAT TO DO IN THIS FUNCTION TO GO BACK TO INITIAL MAINLOOP STATE??
        return


master = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=master)
app.Create_canvas(1920,1080)

app.Application_Intro()
```

The program above will create a simple GUI with 2 buttons. Initially, the program will IDLE and wait for user to start an Application. When application is started, it will call itself recursively ( checking various states and doing other complex operations in my real program), however, I Want to be able to interrupt this operation and stop it at any time. That is why I have created a button "RESTART" which should restart the program back to its initial state where I am waiting for user to start and application again. How can I return out of the Start_program function after the button is pressed?

I cant really find relevant information on the internet apart from master.destroy() or master.quit().

master.destroy() destroys my mainloop completely which is not what I want, and calling master.quit() does not even seem to do anything.

Adding an image url so you can understand it easier:
https://ibb.co/djMd5TW

Comment: If "The program works fine", then what is your problem? As it seems, you are already getting what you want done, but want general advice to do it better. You have to be specific to really get help.

Comment: Exactly as you said. I am hoping to get an advice from someone who has more tkinter experience and could give me general advice whether thats an efficient way to handle the windows since I do not feel like thats very efficient destroying and remaking a new window everytime I start a new operation ( a new operation can be initiated every 30seconds or something like that)

Comment: There will be very little problem with destroying windows regularly as the application runs on the desktop. More concerning will be that it seems you are running more than one instance of `Tk()` (`login_screen` and `window`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using a single instance of Tk() login screen is a toplevel of window. It is being created during the login window as following: ```global login_screen  login_screen = TopLevel(window)```

Comment: You should be good to go. After the application is working you may want to go over and refactor it. But get it working first, which you seem to already have.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much of the program you are willing to rewrite. IMO, the "best-case scenario" would be not deleting the main window and using as few `TopLevel`s as possible. I would recommend instead just creating a series of frames so you can add and remove the entire content of the window very easily. These frames would be your own classes with their parent being `tkinter.Frame` and contain all the logic for that screen.

The reason I am suggesting this is because it appears you have ~700+ lines of methods which (I know from experience ;-) is a real pain to maintain (any more than a few hundred lines and I will start to use the method above). If you want an example of this method, please see the code at the bottom of this answer.

A slightly smaller change, I would recommend you replace your `from tkinter import *` with `import tkinter as tk` as the former creates a very cluttered namespace:

> `from tkinter import *`: This imports the Tkinter library into the global namespace. This isn't best practice, because it fills your namespace with a lot of classes, which you might accidentally overwrite, but it's okay for very small scripts. [[Creating a Tkinter Hello World - Python GUI programming with Tkinter](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781788835886/1/ch01lvl1sec12/creating-a-tkinter-hello-world)]

Another small change I would recommend is to stop creating your own message windows (like that declaring "Login Success") and instead look at the `tkinter.messagebox` module (in that situation, you could use `showinfo`).

If you have *lots* of time on your hands, take a look at the IDLE source as it is a tkinter program that is (generally speaking) very well written (I believe Thonny also uses tkinter).

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk

class Login(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def create_widgets(self):

        # your login screen widgets ...
        # I use this method to stop __init__ becoming too big and also to
        # give me the option to seperate widget creating from
        # instantiation if I wish

        tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=self.check_creds).pack()

    def check_creds(self):

        # mysql and other logic
        # assuming everything is good to go:

        self.destroy()
        Welcome(self.master)

class Welcome(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def create_widgets(self):

        # again, your widgets are created here...

        tk.Button(self, text="Log out", command=self.log_out).pack()

    def log_out(self):
        self.destroy()
        Login(self.master)

root = tk.Tk()
Login(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks sir I will definately have a look at such implementation of GUI and see how far I can go.